# Proper way to take an input of variable sized vector

Tags: c++, vector

I am a beginner in C++ and just started learning vectors.

Can someone suggest me a better way to take in values for a vector ? Or is this method good enough ? Thanks in advance :')

```
vector<int> vec;
int temp;
bool condition=true;
while(condition){

    cin >> temp;
    vec.push_back(temp);
    if(cin.get()=='\n') condition = false;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more C++ish way would probably be to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the line into a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). Then put that string into an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), from which you then use [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) to fill the [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Perhaps something like

```
// Somewhere to put the text we read
std::string line;

// Read the actual text
std::getline(std::cin, line);

// A stream to parse the integers from
std::istringstream iss(line);

// Define the vector, initializing it from stream iterators
// This is a more succinct version of a loop which extracts (with `>>`)
// integers and pushes them into the vector
std::vector<int> vec(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), std::istream_iterator<int>());
```

After this `vec` is filled with integers from a single line of input.

Answer (score -1):

May be you can use C++ stream functions to check whether input stream is good enough to take input from,

```
while(cin.good())
{
    int i;
    cin >> i;
    vec.push_back(i);
}
```

That's it!

Comment: Doing `while (cin.good())` is no better than `while (!cin.eof())` [which is almost always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) (including this case).